Confusion in synthesis of parallel case
I am learning full case and parallel case directives used in synthesis. I am unable to understand what will be the output if "sel" matches "a" as well as "b". My doubt is regarding synthesized output.
module synopsys_parallel_case(input[2:0] sel,a,b,c,
                     output reg[2:0] out);

    always@(sel or a or b or c)
    begin
        case(sel)    //synthesis parallel_case
        a : out = 3'b001;
        b : out = 3'b110;
        c : out = 3'b100;
        default : out = 3'b000;
        endcase
    end
endmodule


Normally a case statement evaluates its expressions in priority order. If sel, a and b have matching values, branch a is taken, which consumes extra logic. When using parallel_case, you are telling your synthesis tool to optimize the logic assuming only there is only one match at a time. The output your synthesized logic has when there is more than one match is unpredictable. The parallel_case directive tells only the synthesis tool that you do not care about multiple matches either because you think it will never happen, or because when it does, you are not planning to use the result.
SystemVerilog adds a unique case statement that generates an error when there is more than one match. This helps find simulation/synthesis logic differences.
